# In which event loop does a coroutine run when using yield from?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

When I call `yield from some_coroutine()` from with in a couroutine `foo`, is `some_coroutine` scheduled in the same even-loop as `foo` is currently running in? An example:

```
async def foo():
    yield from asyncio.sleep(5)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop() # this could also be a custom event loop
loop.run_until_completed(foo())
```

In this example, in which event-loop will `sleep` be scheduled? I'm especially interested in the case where `loop` is not the default event-loop.

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html), under *"Things a coroutine can do"* says:

> `result = await coroutine` or `result = yield from coroutine` – wait for
>   another coroutine to produce a result (or raise an exception, which
>   will be propagated). The `coroutine` expression must be a call to
>   another coroutine.

It is not clear to me in which loop the coroutine will be scheduled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Citing docs of [`get_event_loop`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloops.html#asyncio.AbstractEventLoopPolicy.get_event_loop)

> Get the event loop for the current context.

Implementation of [default loop](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloops.html#event-loop-policies-and-the-default-policy) (*Event loop default policy* to be precise):

> The default policy defines context as the current thread, and manages an event loop per thread that interacts with asyncio.

- An event loop runs in a thread and executes all callbacks and tasks in the same thread ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-dev.html#concurrency-and-multithreading)),
- `asyncio.get_event_loop` returns the same loop for the same thread,
- if you do not explicitly schedule on/interact with different thread's loop, it will use default (*****) loop

In your example:

1. `get_event_loop` returns current thread's event loop,
2. `foo` is scheduled on that loop with `run_until_completed`
3. any further async calls (awaits/yield from) are scheduled on the same loop

More info at [Concurrency and multithreading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-dev.html#concurrency-and-multithreading).

(*****) The event loop you called *default* is actually a loop of current thread.

Comment: Thank you very much, that clarifies it. I'm wondering though, since *explicit is better than implicit*, should explicitly passing the event loop be the preferred style?

Comment: Should every function (e.g. file i/o) require a explicit thread passed (and dozen of other params)? keep the balance :)